# Stop when error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

In python, I am using selenium to scrape a webpage. There is a button that I need to repeatedly click until there is no button anymore. So far, I have code like:

```
count = 20

while count:
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name('buttontext')[0].click()
    count-=1
```

The problem is that I don't actually know how many times I need to do this - `count = 20` is incorrect. What I actually need is for it to keep going until the command encounters an error (`IndexError: list index out of range`), and then stop. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the *[EAFP approach](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)* - make an endless loop and break it once there is no element found:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

while True:
    try:
        button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("buttontext")
        button.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this?

```
while True:
   try:
       driver.find_elements_by_class_name('buttontext')[0].click()

   except IndexError:
       break
```

> `try` will try to run some code, and `except` can capture the error that you select.
>
> And if you didn't select an error, `except` will capture all errors. [For more info](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: if you're always going to use the 0th item, you might as well use `find_element_by_class_name()` instead, e.g. `driver.find_element_by_class_name('buttontext').click()`

Comment: @JeffC actually I don't know what does `driver.find_element_by_class_name('buttontext').click()` do, I just answer how to _Stop when error_.

Comment: Sorry... I was wrong. You will hit `IndexError` in this case. Removing my comment.

Comment: @JeffC Okay, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [try statement](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to handle exceptions. It will run your code until it finds an exception. Your code should look something like that:

```
try:
    while True:
        click_function() 
except Exception: #as Exception being your error 
    got_an_error()  #or just a pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the [Selenium docs' recommendation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) and use `.findElements()`.

> findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use
>   findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead.

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("buttontext")
while buttons:
    buttons[0].click()
    // might need a slight pause here depending on what your click triggers
    buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("buttontext")
```

Comment: Btw, it could be simplified to just `while buttons:`. And, you've probably meant `buttons[0]` (watch the `s`).

Comment: Yes...thanks. I'm trying to learn basic python so I can answer these simple questions and not get downvoted for using Java... ;)

Comment: Got it. For some reason, I don't fully understand the recommendation - checking the length of `find_elements_*()` call results sounds quite "unnatural" and non-pythonic to me..eafp approach is quite readable and easily understandable - it's just my opinion.

Comment: Well, in general, exceptions are supposed to be exceptional... rare and unexpected. You shouldn't, IMHO (and others), rely on exceptions for normal code flow. So, in this case, you get the list of elements and make sure it's of non-zero length and then click it.

Comment: Thanks. Well, in general, it's arguable, here is a good read: https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/06/write-cleaner-python-use-exceptions/.

Comment: I agree it's arguable. My general philosophy for exceptions is don't catch exceptions you aren't going to handle and don't rely on exceptions if there is another way. This comes from my background in C# and more recently Java. I really have very limited knowledge when it comes to python so I can't speak to how pythonic this thinking is.